# Why is Chrome bailing on this gradient setting?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm not getting a gradient in Chrome, but it works in Safari and Firefox. Here is the code:

```
.accounts-form #auth-form {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FEFEFE, #F4F4F4) repeat scroll 0 0 #F4F4F4;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 40px;
}
```

It's that `background:` line that is causing the issue. I have seen other people have the issue with `-webkit-gradient`, just not `-moz-linear-gradient`.

Comment: Don't you *need* a webkit gradient style there, for webkit browsers?

Comment: The gradient declaration looks wrong for the gradient.  It wouldn't surprise me if Chrome was choking on it if you copied it with a webkit prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome needs a -webkit-gradient; and Chrome 10+ uses a slightly different -webkit-gradient than some earlier versions I believe.

I use this CSS3 gradient generator - whether or not you use the generated code, it gives a good idea of all the properties you will need for each browser.

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 1):

The following is the syntax of how a gradient should be applied over a background.

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
```

It is usually advised to write the code in native version and then run it through http://prefixr.com/ to complete the code with all the browser compatible vendor-prefixes.